# Validity of nikah - revert

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

Hello I am wondering if my nikah is still considered valid… I am a revert so when I married my husband and I just supposed that I didn’t have any wali, so we just got a guy from the mosque to be it for me… after a year of marriage we realized that my uncle on my dads side of the family is Muslim (he converted only because of marriage, so he isn’t practicing. Also I don’t really have any relationship with him and I rarely see/talk to him)
Now my question is, is my nikah valid? I did it without any family present only a guy from the mosque and my husbands family.

Comment: We are not a fatwa site and do not give legal verdicts. The answer depends on various factors: (i) the requirement of a wali for validity of nikah is disagreed upon (ii) a proven 'pretend only' muslim who does not believe in Islam in reality is not a muslim and can not be a wali (iii) a fasiq i.e. impious muslim can not the wali depending on the madhab. And there are also other factors to be considered.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we are not a fatwa site.

Answer (score -1):

It is allowed to choose an Imam as a Wali if no family member is available, be it that no Muslim is alive, known and available (which can also be due to visa problems. In your case, not your uncle but his suitability was unknown to you.

It's also allowed that a mature women deliberately chooses an Imam as a Wali, see [here](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/172129/girl-marrying-without-a-wali/). So, your nikkah is certainly valid.